# Progressive enhancement and react

Tags: reactjs, progressive-enhancement

Am I right in saying that it is impossible to do progressive enhancement without some form of server side rendering.

A static build of a react application will not meet the requirements of a PE application.

Is there anything that can be done with service workers for example that would allow us to deploy a static build?

Comment: I would very much like to know the same thing - I haven't found anyone discussing this which surprises me.

Comment: Having read a bit more this may provide a solution: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need some form of server-side rendering in order to do progressive enhancement with React.

The obvious solution is to render HTML with [react-dom/server](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server) and then [hydrate](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot) it. Frameworks like `next.js` do this for you. Components like [`<form>`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/form#handle-form-submission-with-a-server-action) are starting to support progressive enhancement so that they can be used even if JavaScript is disabled, as mentioned in the documentation.

Otherwise, if you render HTML outside of React's control (say, with Django), then progressive enhancement is still possible, but the frontend will have to figure out which elements need to be enhanced by React, then create a root for each of those elements and render over them. Or, create one root (e.g. to share context) and then use [createPortal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) to render over the elements. Cf. also a [React issue on hydrating portals](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13097), which may be related. There is even a way to [preserve DOM elements](https://dev.to/oosawy/rfc-keeping-real-dom-elements-across-renders-in-react-401l) inside of React elements, which might even allow you to enclose server-rendered DOM elements with React elements.

Finally, if your content is fairly static, then [static-site generation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/static-site-generation) might also be an option that would allow progressive enhancement.